# Reduce CPU and GPU Power Consumption

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, cpu, power-supply, battery

I have a gaming laptop (i5-10300H and RTX2060 - Intel Gateway Creator Series), and as expected, it has sub-par battery life, especially because it is so powerful. However, I don't need this power all of the time, especially when I'm running smaller battery power applications. When I'm on battery power, how can I reduce the CPU and GPU's power consumption?

For the CPU, I've gone into Control Panel -> Power Options and reduced the CPU percentage to 66% on battery power. I've made the preferred graphics processor on the NVIDIA control panel as the integrated graphics on Optimus.

Even with this, I still get about 10 W of power on the CPU and 5 W of power on the GPU, even when the computer is idle. How can I further reduce CPU usage, and if possible, how can I turn off the GPU and use integrated graphics when I'm on battery power? Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: *"it has sub-par battery life"* -- As the battery ages and also if abused, the battery capacity will diminish.  Underclocking can reduce power consumption.  Keeping the laptop cool (clean out dust, provide good air circulation) can also help.

Comment: @sawdust It's a brand new laptop I got a few days ago, I've limited the CPU clock to 3GHZ out of 4.5 on battery, and it's usually around 30-40ºC. In addition I just disabled the discrete GPU, but I still get about 2-3 hours of battery life. How can I make this better?